# upgrading to mariadb 10.11.* (or later) on Rocky 8.5

Tags: linux, mariadb, rocky-os

We use Rocky 8.5 and are currently on the default version of Mariadb (10.3) which I'd like to upgrade to a more recent version, 10.11.* or later. But when I checked the Appstream modules the only other available version is 10.5.

There's plenty of documentation out there for doing new installs of more recent Maria versions (inc. setting up a separate Maria repo) but nothing so far that explains *why* a full re-install is necessary rather than having later versions available for upgrade.

Is Mariadb not really supported on Rocky? Should we even be trying to upgrade past 10.5? If we have a Maria repo, should Appstream be unenabled?

Comment: Not sure how a [mariadb repo](https://mariadb.org/download/?t=repo-config&d=Red+Hat+Enterprise+Linux+8) implies a "full reinstall", its a repo providing updates. There are MariaDB Rocky tests in CI, but a lot depends on Rocky being compatible with RHEL. `module_hotfixes = 1` (a hack that needs fixing for true modular support) in the MariaDB repo should always give priority there over Appstream.

Comment: Thanks @danblack - I didn't mean to imply that setting up a mariadb repo equates to an install, just that a lot of installation instructions suggest setting one up, but don't really explain why. So, if I understand correctly, it's because the `module_hotfixes = 1` in the Maria repo overrides the Appstream repo, right?

Comment: There's a repo to provide versions that are not in appstream. `module_hotfixes` is a packaging oversight that needs fixing to enable the modular support.

Comment: Cheers @danblack, I think I have a better handle on things now. Thanks again for your reply.